# Sending an image with Retrofit2

Tags: php, kotlin, request, retrofit

I am trying to send an image taken with the cell phone camera and send it later to a server, however I cannot successfully connect my Kotlin code with php. This is my Kotlin code:

```
`import android.Manifest
import android.annotation.SuppressLint
import android.content.ContentValues
import android.content.Context
import android.content.pm.PackageManager
import android.net.Uri
import android.os.Build
import android.os.Bundle
import android.view.LayoutInflater
import android.view.View
import android.view.ViewGroup
import android.widget.Button
import android.widget.ProgressBar
import androidx.annotation.RequiresApi
import androidx.core.app.ActivityCompat
import androidx.core.content.ContextCompat
import androidx.core.view.isVisible
import android.content.Intent
import android.provider.MediaStore
import android.util.Log
import android.widget.ImageView
import android.widget.Toast
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity
import com.google.gson.JsonObject
import com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName
import kotlinx.coroutines.Dispatchers
import kotlinx.coroutines.GlobalScope
import kotlinx.coroutines.launch
import okhttp3.MediaType.Companion.toMediaType
import okhttp3.MultipartBody
import okhttp3.RequestBody
import okhttp3.RequestBody.Companion.asRequestBody
import retrofit2.Response
import retrofit2.Retrofit
import retrofit2.converter.gson.GsonConverterFactory
import retrofit2.http.Multipart
import retrofit2.http.POST
import retrofit2.http.Part
import java.io.File
import java.io.IOException
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat
import java.util.Date
import java.util.Locale

val titulo_ = "${Global_Class.codigo_cliente}/${Global_Class.circuito_actual}/${Global_Class.codigoFin}"

class c_CamaraDocOfi(var eq:superEQ, var pregunta:String, var monto:String, var respuesta:String): superFragment(eq,"","") {
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    private val CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST = 100
    private val CAMERA_REQUEST = 101
    private var imageUri: Uri? = null
    private lateinit var imageViewFoto: ImageView // Agregamos la referencia al ImageView



    @SuppressLint("MissingInflatedId")
    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onCreateView(
        inflater: LayoutInflater, container: ViewGroup?,
        savedInstanceState: Bundle?
    ): View? {
        val v: View = inflater.inflate(R.layout.c_camaradocofi_frag, container, false)

        val sig = activity?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.siguiente_sec)
        if (sig != null && r == "") sig.isVisible = false
        if (sig != null && r != "") sig.isVisible = true
        val barra = activity?.findViewById<ProgressBar>(R.id.progressBar)
        val ant = activity?.findViewById<Button>(R.id.atras_sec)
        if (barra != null) {
            barra.min = 0
            barra.max = e.sc.size + 1
            barra.progress = e.nav + 1
        }

        if (sig != null) {
            sig.isVisible = true
            sig.setText("Siguiente")
        }
        imageViewFoto = v.findViewById(R.id.fotoimagen)

        val openCameraButton = v.findViewById<Button>(R.id.open_camera_button)
        openCameraButton.setOnClickListener {
            if (sig != null) {
                sig.setText("Siguiente")

                if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(
                        requireContext(),
                        Manifest.permission.CAMERA
                    ) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED
                ) {
                    openCamera()
                } else {
                    ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(
                        requireActivity(),
                        arrayOf(Manifest.permission.CAMERA),
                        CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST
                    )
                }
            }
            else if (sig != null) {
                sig.isVisible = true
                sig.setText("No se pudo tomar la fotografía")
            }
        }

        if (ant != null) {
            ant.setOnClickListener { v ->
                if (sig != null){
                    sig.setText("Siguiente")
                    sig.isVisible = false
                }
            }
        }

        sig?.setOnClickListener{
            cambio(true,eq.next())
        }
        ant?.setOnClickListener{
            cambio(true, eq.back())
        }

        return v
    }

    private fun openCamera() {
        val values = ContentValues()
        val timeStamp: String = SimpleDateFormat("yyyyMMdd_HHmmss", Locale.getDefault()).format(
            Date()
        )

        // Concatena el valor de "titulo" en el nombre del archivo de imagen
        val imageFileName = "$titulo_.jpg"

        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.TITLE, imageFileName)
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.DISPLAY_NAME, imageFileName)
        values.put(MediaStore.Images.Media.MIME_TYPE, "image/jpeg")

        imageUri = requireContext().contentResolver.insert(
            MediaStore.Images.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI,
            values
        )
        val intent = Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE)
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, imageUri)
        startActivityForResult(intent, CAMERA_REQUEST)
    }

    private fun enviarImage(imageUri: Uri) {
        val filePath = getPathFromUri(imageUri)

        // Verifica si se pudo obtener la ruta del archivo desde la URI
        if (filePath != null) {
            val file = File(filePath)

            // Verifica si el archivo existe y es un archivo regular
            if (file.exists() && file.isFile) {
                val requestBody = file.asRequestBody("image/jpeg".toMediaType())
                val imagePart = MultipartBody.Part.createFormData("img", file.name, requestBody)

                val id = Global_Class.codigoFin
                val cliente = Global_Class.codigo_cliente

                // Crea una instancia del servicio web utilizando Retrofit
                val webService: WebService = RetrofitClient.webService

                // Ejecuta la solicitud en un hilo en segundo plano utilizando coroutines
                GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.IO) {
                    try {
                        // Realiza la llamada a la función del servicio web para enviar la imagen
                        val response = webService.enviarImage(id, cliente, imagePart)

                        // Verifica si la respuesta del servidor fue exitosa (código 200)
                        if (response.isSuccessful) {
                            val jsonObject = response.body()

                            // Puedes realizar las operaciones necesarias con la respuesta del servidor aquí
                            requireActivity().runOnUiThread {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    requireContext(),
                                    "Imagen enviada exitosamente",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                ).show()
                            }
                        } else {
                            // Error en la respuesta del servidor
                            requireActivity().runOnUiThread {
                                Toast.makeText(
                                    requireContext(),
                                    "Error al enviar la imagen",
                                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                                ).show()
                            }
                        }
                    } catch (e: Exception) {
                        // Error en la conexión o en el procesamiento de la solicitud
                        e.printStackTrace()
                        requireActivity().runOnUiThread {
                            Toast.makeText(
                                requireContext(),
                                "Error al enviar la imagen",
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                            ).show()
                        }
                    }
                }
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(
                    requireContext(),
                    "El archivo de imagen no existe o no es un archivo regular",
                    Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                ).show()
            }
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(
                requireContext(),
                "No se pudo obtener la ruta del archivo desde la URI",
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
            ).show()
        }
    }



    private fun getPathFromUri(uri: Uri): String? {
        var path: String? = null
        val projection = arrayOf(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
        val cursor = context?.contentResolver?.query(uri, projection, null, null, null)
        cursor?.use {
            if (it.moveToFirst()) {
                val columnIndex = it.getColumnIndexOrThrow(MediaStore.Images.Media.DATA)
                path = it.getString(columnIndex)
            }
        }
        return path
    }


    private fun getAppContext(): Context? {
        return activity?.applicationContext
    }


    @RequiresApi(Build.VERSION_CODES.O)
    override fun onRequestPermissionsResult(
        requestCode: Int,
        permissions: Array<String>,
        grantResults: IntArray
    ) {
        super.onRequestPermissionsResult(requestCode, permissions, grantResults)
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_PERMISSION_REQUEST) {
            if (grantResults.isNotEmpty() && grantResults[0] == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
                openCamera()
            } else {
                Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Permiso de cámara denegado", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            }
        }
    }

    override fun onActivityResult(requestCode: Int, resultCode: Int, data: Intent?) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data)
        if (requestCode == CAMERA_REQUEST && resultCode == AppCompatActivity.RESULT_OK) {
            // Foto tomada con éxito, puedes realizar las operaciones necesarias con la imagen URI aquí
            Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Foto tomada con éxito y guardada en el dispositivo", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
            imageViewFoto.setImageURI(imageUri)
            if (imageUri != null) {
                try {
                    // Aquí puedes realizar las operaciones necesarias con la imagen URI,
                    // como guardarla en la galería sin utilizar Bitmap
                    Toast.makeText(requireContext(), "Imagen guardada: $imageUri", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
                    Log.d("Photo", "Imagen guardada: $imageUri")
                    // Envía la imagen al servidor
                    enviarImage(imageUri!!)
                } catch (e: IOException) {
                    e.printStackTrace()
                    Toast.makeText(
                        requireContext(),
                        "Error al guardar la imagen",
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show()
                }
            }
        }
    }

}

interface WebService {
    @Multipart
    @POST("upload.php")
    suspend fun enviarImage(
        @Part("id") id: String,
        @Part("cliente") cliente: String,
        @Part img: MultipartBody.Part
    ): Response<JsonObject>
}


object RetrofitClient {
    private const val BASE_URL = "URL"

    val webService: WebService by lazy {
        val retrofit = Retrofit.Builder()
            .baseUrl(BASE_URL)
            .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
            .build()

        retrofit.create(WebService::class.java)
    }
}

data class ImageModel(
    @SerializedName("id")
    var id: RequestBody,
    @SerializedName("cliente")
    var cliente: RequestBody,
    @SerializedName("img")
    var img: String
)`
```

And my php code is the following:

```
<?php

if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'POST') {
    $id = $_POST['id']; // Obtener el valor del campo 'id'
    $cliente = $_POST['cliente']; // Obtener el valor del campo 'cliente'
    
    $uploadsDir = 'uploads/'; // Directorio donde se almacenarán las imágenes
    
    // Verificar si se recibió correctamente la imagen
    if (isset($_FILES['img']) && $_FILES['img']['error'] === UPLOAD_ERR_OK) {
        $tmpName = $_FILES['img']['tmp_name']; // Ruta temporal de la imagen
        $fileName = $_FILES['img']['name']; // Nombre original de la imagen
        
        // Mover la imagen del directorio temporal al directorio de destino
        if (move_uploaded_file($tmpName, $uploadsDir . $fileName)) {
            echo json_encode(['message' => 'Imagen recibida exitosamente']);
        } else {
            echo json_encode(['error' => 'No se pudo mover la imagen al directorio de destino']);
        }
    } else {
        echo json_encode(['error' => 'No se pudo recibir la imagen']);
    }
} else {
    echo json_encode(['error' => 'Método no permitido']);
}
```

I have managed to send a few samples of the images, however these are empty files. I have tried to change the file type from "String" to RequestBody in the WebService without success